# Reordering pixel values in a stack of rasters

Tags: raster, r

Consider a vector dataset of 228 observations

```
precip<-c(3.287516e+00,3.012129e+00,7.450114e+01,5.232168e+00,8.328000e+00,9.426842e+01,3.952095e+02,
 3.116342e+02,2.276140e+02,1.608153e+01,3.258420e+01,0.000000e+00,5.485738e+00,9.192645e+01,
 2.943402e-01,2.280000e-01,1.752476e+01,1.351948e+02,4.482827e+02,3.531432e+02,6.959639e+02,
 1.379384e+02,9.000000e-01,6.720001e-01,0.000000e+00,1.974000e+00,0.000000e+00,2.982000e+00,
 2.726213e+01,1.399524e+02,6.766090e+02,1.935723e+02,4.636400e+01,3.309727e-01,8.099999e-01,
 2.952000e+00,5.683278e+00,7.083724e-03,2.668146e+00,1.628295e+01,3.548195e+01,2.934440e+02,
 3.024660e+02, 1.382988e+02, 3.707115e+01, 5.961257e+01, 0.000000e+00, 3.600000e-02, 0.000000e+00,
 3.055869e+01,1.139865e+01,3.723898e+00,1.036747e+01,1.062829e+02,1.005832e+02,5.299438e+02,
 7.339809e+01, 4.536283e+00, 8.922304e+00, 0.000000e+00, 1.098449e+00,8.125899e+01,6.968601e-03,
 9.240000e-01, 0.000000e+00, 1.238425e+02, 2.596544e+02, 2.374932e+02, 3.476996e+02, 0.000000e+00,
 3.909159e-01, 0.000000e+00, 5.711232e+01, 9.000000e-02, 0.000000e+00, 2.136000e+00, 2.434159e+01, 
 3.015469e+02, 2.186706e+02, 2.877532e+02,6.169636e+01, 2.438971e+01, 2.373664e+00, 1.315564e+00,
 7.095953e+00, 1.740000e-01, 3.288097e+01, 2.742000e+00, 1.638000e+00, 1.247376e+02, 9.973801e+02,
 1.199484e+02, 1.901760e+02, 7.984202e-01, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 4.324105e-01,
 7.113221e+01, 4.140000e+00, 5.404327e+01, 8.203735e+01, 4.207430e+02, 4.862388e+02, 1.329529e+02,
 7.671657e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 6.360000e-01, 2.518633e+01,0.000000e+00, 2.124000e+00,
 2.677887e+01, 8.775770e+01, 2.946802e+02, 1.800176e+02, 1.420970e+02, 0.000000e+00, 2.400000e-02,
 0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 4.649093e+00, 4.426157e+00, 4.831618e+00, 3.774218e+02,
 2.771018e+02, 2.202528e+02, 1.217157e+02, 7.763163e+00, 9.600000e-01, 6.000000e-03, 1.256319e+01,
 0.000000e+00, 6.000000e-02, 1.224000e+00, 1.692969e+01, 1.054706e+02, 3.525440e+02, 2.389812e+02, 
 2.442882e+02, 7.527153e+01, 6.778238e+01, 1.358918e+01, 1.102953e+01, 3.551746e+00, 0.000000e+00,
 1.140000e-01, 4.440000e-01, 7.078428e+01, 3.542093e+02, 2.461660e+02, 1.025227e+02, 3.087413e+01,
 5.262804e+01, 6.300000e-01, 0.000000e+00, 1.676579e+00,1.398000e+00, 1.664469e+00, 2.012430e+01,
 4.735457e+02, 3.973598e+02, 3.091013e+02, 1.914775e+02, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00,
 1.831472e+01, 0.000000e+00, 1.524202e-02, 7.800000e-01, 5.477224e+00, 7.821223e+01, 3.506086e+02,
 3.987886e+02,8.562125e+01, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00, 2.404258e+01,
 2.571477e+01, 6.611002e+00, 0.000000e+00, 5.205880e+02, 5.405767e+02, 5.016281e+02 ,5.492355e+01,
 5.706278e+01,2.250000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 6.612912e+01, 9.587150e+01, 3.960000e+00, 1.074052e+01,
 1.614000e+00, 9.181252e+01, 4.643691e+02, 1.932034e+02, 1.541364e+02, 9.265393e+00, 0.000000e+00,
 3.816947e+01, 2.979000e+01, 6.305477e+00, 6.317532e+01, 8.266569e+00, 5.865227e+00, 1.847435e+02,
 3.620533e+02, 2.988630e+02 ,5.844741e+01, 0.000000e+00, 3.480975e-01, 0.000000e+00, 2.760000e+00,
 2.010000e+00, 2.712000e+01, 2.640000e+00, 2.123399e+01, 1.456584e+02, 7.809321e+02, 5.340542e+02,
 9.234533e+01, 2.354917e+01, 0.000000e+00,0.000000e+00)
```

These are monthly precipitation at a location over a number of years. I find the mean of all the Jans, all the Febs, all the Mar etc

```
x<-rowMeans(matrix(precip, nrow = 12, byrow = F))
x
11.630832  19.372524  16.788150   4.051670  14.857163 186.173774 420.738594 304.162227 161.079527 23.955036   8.945979   3.019485
```

Then I find the index of the maximum value of x

```
wetMo<-which(x==max(x)) 
wetMo
7 # 420.738 is the maximum value in x
```

Then I reorder the precip vector such that the 7th value is the start of the series. I do this by

```
if(wetMo > 1) precip[c(wetMo:(length(precip) - (13-wetMo)))] else precip
```

Above reorders precip, such that the first value is 3.952 (which is the 7th value in the original vector).

I want to do the above for a stack of raster over a region. I have 360 rasters of monthly precip for 30 years. I have found the mean of all the Jans, Febs etc and created a raster by

```
mean_monthly_ppt<-stackApply(pptStack, c(1:12), fun = mean) #12 rasters created which I stack again
```

Then I have found the maximum precip value in the above stack by

```
x<-which.max(mean_monthly_ppt_stack)
```

Now I want to do the reordering with a similar if statement as I have written above for the vector, but in a function that I will use with calc

```
reorder<-function(r_s){
 if (any(is.na(r_s))) return(r_s*NA)
 r_s_reorder <- if(x > 1) r_s[c(x:((length(r_s) - (13-x)))] else r_s
 return(r_s_reorder)
}
reorder_ppt<-calc(pptStack, fun=reorder)
```

However, I get the error Error in if (x > 1) r_s[c(x:((length(r_s) - 1) - (13 - x)))] else r_s :
argument is not interpretable as logical

I cannot figure this out because I have tried the function on a vector and it works but it does not with the calc().

Comment: I would just create a vector of the new ordering and not attempt to apply a function to `calc`. You can then simply pass that vector as an index to the stack eg., `reorder_ppt <- pptStack[[order.idx]]` I do this type of operation to ensure that after reading in a timeseries of separate rasters, that the resulting stack is then ordered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `x` as you have defined it is a raster layer, not a single value. So when you run the logical test `(x > 1)`, it evaluates to another raster layer and not the TRUE/FALSE value expected by the `if` statement, hence the error "not interpretable as logical".

You need to rewrite the function to include the calculation of `x` at a pixel-level, i.e. for a vector rather than RasterStack. Since I don't think there's an equivalent of `stackApply()` for a vector, you'll need to do the calculation step-by-step. One option is to use the modulo function `%%` to group the values for like months (all Januarys, Februarys etc.) across the vector and use `sapply` to calculate the mean for each.

The first line will also give you an error here, as you're returning an NA vector of the same length as `r_s`, while the later code returns a different length vector. Similarly, I don't think you actually want the if statement here, since if x = 1 you would still want to cut off the final 12 months to avoid returning a vector of a different length to other cells.

Here's a modified version that seems to work on a test rasterstack:

```
reorder <- function(r_s) {
  if(any(is.nan(r_s)) | any(is.na(r_s[1]))) {
    return(rep(NA, length.out = (length(r_s) - 12)))
  } else {
    months <- 1:12

    # New function to calculate mean for each month across years
    monthly_mean <- function(month_number, vector) {
      month_indices <- (1:length(vector) - 1) %% 12 + 1 == month_number
      month_mean <- mean(vector[month_indices])
      month_mean
    }
    
    # Apply function for each month
    monthly_mean_ppt <- sapply(months, monthly_mean, vector = r_s)

    x <- which.max(monthly_mean_ppt)

    r_s_reorder <- r_s[x:(length(r_s) - (13 - x))]
    return(r_s_reorder)
  }
}

reorder_ppt <- calc(pptStack, fun = reorder)
```